# Json Displayed as individual format

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I successfully get the Wordpress post comments via PHP code. Now I want to display all the post comments in JSON format. I referred some examples to complete that progress, but all the comments (JSON format) displayed individually.

See the sample result:

```
[{
    "author": "JimmiXzSq",
    "comment": "test1"
}]

[{
    "author": "MoseJackswka",
    "comment": "test2"
}]
```

But I want to display correct JSON format

My workout code:

```
foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :

  $getauthor = $comment->comment_author ;
  $getcontent =  $comment->comment_content;
  $test1=  array('author' => $getauthor, 'comment' => $getcontent);

  $displaycomments = json_encode(array(($test1)),true);
  echo $displaycomments;
endforeach;
```

Comment: It's because you json_encode each bit separately inside the loop. So they are treated as invididual, separate pieces of JSON, not one big list. There is no link between them. Instead, build a single PHP object / array containing all the data, and then json_encode that object once after your loop finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert all your comments in one json:

```
$comments = array();

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
    $getauthor = $comment->comment_author ;
    $getcontent =  $comment->comment_content;
    $tmp=  array('author' => $getauthor, 'comment' => $getcontent);

    $comment[] = $tmp;
endforeach;

$displaycomments = json_encode($comments);
echo $displaycomments ;
```

will give

```
{
    {
        "author": "JimmiXzSq",
        "comment": "test1"
    }
    ,
    {
        "author": "MoseJackswka",
        "comment": "test2"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable response, but one small problem.  after try your code , display all the fields like comment id, comment time some like that.   I want display particular field only ( author and comment)           $comments = get_comments( $args );
 
 
foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
    
    $getauthor = $comment->comment_author ;
    $getcontent =  $comment->comment_content;$tmp=  array('author' => $getauthor, 'comment' => $getcontent);

   // $comment[] = $tmp;
endforeach;

$displaycomments = json_encode($comments);
echo $displaycomments ;     my original code

Comment: I don't really understand... Your json contains "comment author", "comment id", "comment time", "comment text"...  And you just want to display specific informations. And my code display all informations?